# html div containing graph will not increase in size not matter how many pixels I put

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I am using Dash to create a webpage but I think this is a html/ CSS problem I am not understanding. I am trying to increase the height size of a graph I have placed in an `html.Div` but when using the `height` style it makes no difference to the size of my graph. Here is my code:

```
layout_page1 = \
html.Div([
    html.H1('Live Stock Analysis',
            style={'textAlign': 'center'}
            ),
    html.H2('Bollinger Bands Analysis'),
    html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='candlestick_plot', figure=candlestick)],
             style={'height': '2000px',  'width': '1500px'}) ## HERE IS THE STYLING
         ],
         style={'margin-top': '20px', 'margin-bottom': '20px',
                'margin-right': '150px', 'margin-left': '80px'}
         ),
```

The `<div>` I am trying to style contains the `dcc.graph` and have tried heights of 200, 1500 and 2000px but all are exactly the same size.

What exactly am I doing wrong here as it doesn't make logical sense to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.html: this exp is to tell to html code: i need 2000 px height for my dash div

```
<body>
  <div id="dash_dash">
        {% load plotly_dash %}
        {% with  ***** %}
            {% plotly_app name="****" initial_arguments=**** %}
        {% endwith %}
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var list = document.getElementById("dash_dash");
list.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].style.position = "relative";
list.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0].style.height = "2000px";
});
</script>
```

.py: an exp an app layout

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.P('****', style={}), => html paragraph
        html.H2('***', style={}), => html title
        dcc.Dropdown(id='****',
                    options=[{'label': s, 'value': s}for s in ****],
                    value='',
                    multi=False
                ), => a dropdown. With values in a list and an initial value. You can't select multiple values
        dcc.Interval(
                id='*****',
                interval=1*5000,
                n_intervals=0,
                ),
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='***', animate=False,
                            figure={'data': [],
                                    'layout': go.Layout(
                                         xaxis=dict(range=[,], ),
                                         yaxis=dict(range=[,]),),
                                    'style': {}})], => the html style of the graph
                 id='****'),
],
    id='***',
    style={} the html style of this div
    )
```

I use dash in my app and it's realy amazing

Comment: Could you explain your answer please.

Comment: feel free to let me know if i forgot something

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't really explain why my solution is not working. I was hoping to understand the logic behind what is going on and why mine is failing.

Comment: You need to first style the top div in html page(a 2000px height ).  After that add an id and style to each div. And a style to the figure of each graph